# Getting unable to identify the xpath where as i copied xpath from IDE and using in my code

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find the element using selenium locator but getting unable to find element tried with all locators

After trying to find element by all locator i sed selenium IDE and copied xpath from IDE and used but still getting same error message

```
System.setProperty("IEDriverServer", "C:\\Users\\cc301438\\Downloads\\Browser-Setup\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("https://netbank.nedsecure.co.za/Browser/Brands/Nedbank/Logon/Logon.aspx");

        driver.findElement(By.id("ProfileId")).sendKeys("46732258");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PinNo")).sendKeys("8026");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("test123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("img[@id='LoginPagelet_LogonID']")).click();

        driver.quit();
```

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to find element with xpath == img[@id='LoginPagelet_LogonID']
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.3.0', revision: 'unknown', time: '2011-08-03 19:22:45'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version:
>   RemoteWebDriver   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:405)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:266)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:323)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:185)
>     at com.firstTest.SimpleDemo.Login.main(Login.java:33)

Comment: You should check the syntax of xpath. It should start with '//'. It should be like this - By.xpath("//img[@id='LoginPagelet_LogonID']")

Comment: Thanks above solution is working

Answer (score 0):

@user3686241, hi. 
Attaching You PDF with best XPath locator practices below:
[image: xpath locators best practices, part 1]
[image: xpath locators best practices, part 2]

So in Your case correct locator should look : 
.....

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("test123");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='LoginPagelet_LogonID']")).click();

 driver.quit();
```

Two `//` mean - to find all elements on HTML page with img tag and **ID** attribute being equal to *LoginPagelet_LogonID*.